# assign variables to an array

Tags: python, list

I have the following line (note: the convert function returns an array):

```
question, answer = convert(snippet, phrase)
```

Does this assign the first two values in the array to `question` and `answer` variables respectively?

Comment: What did you try to find the solution by yourself ?

Answer (score 0):

If the function returns a list of at least two values, you can do:

```
question, answer = convert(snippet, phrase)[:2]
#or 
question, answer, *_ = convert(snippet, phrase)
```

For example:

```
# valid multiple assignment/unpacking
x,y = 1, 2
x,y = [1,2,3][:2]
x,y, *z = [1, 2, 3, 4] # * -> put the rest as the list to z
x, y, *_z = [1, 2, 3, 4] # similar as above but, uses a 'throwaway' variable _

#invalid
x, y = 1, 2, 3 #ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is referred to as *[unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)* in Python.

```
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
# a -> 1
# b -> 2
# c -> 3
```